# Were the temples anointed?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, mishkan-tabernacle, oil

Exodus 30:22-31 and Leviticus 8 describe the procedure for making holy oil and anointing the tabernacle. Did this action suffice for all time, or was an 'anointing' repeated when Solomon built the temple, and again when it was completed the 2nd time?

Comment: Note that they did not have the oil for the second temple and the oil was only made by Moshe rabbeinu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rashi comments on Shemoth 30:31 (referring to Horayoth 11b) that the phrase *"for your generations"* means that the original 12 logs of oil will be used to perform the anointing when the Temple will be rebuilt. This suggests also that it was used for Solomon's Temple as well. The next amud (12a) states that the jar with the oil was later hidden in the Holy Ark by King Yoshiyahu. However, the fate of the Holy Ark is a matter of debate in Yoma 53b (either taken to Babylon or hidden), but it was surely not found during the Second Temple, therefore it couldn't be used to do it.

Comment: Yes, I think this answer makes good sense.

Comment: @ChristianGedge Then please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick symbol! :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234

Comment: Done.  The tick looks a little like a ‘down’ arrow.